# SQLiteManger panel in MAMP Pro gives me blank page

Tags: sqlite, mamp, administration, sqlitemanager

I've recently began looking at administrating SQLite databases through a GUI and would like to try out SQLite Manager which comes bundled with MAMP Pro, however trying to access the tool from its panel (through "Webstart") gives me a blank page. I was assuming it would be preconfigured in the same manner as PhpMyAdmin, any ideas on where to start? Using MAMP Pro 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

Seems you're using too new version of PHP. Try using the lower Version of PHP in MAMP. This fixed it for me.

KK

Comment: I had to back down to 5.2.17 from 5.5.3